# how to add cross term in logistic regression model?

Tags: logistic-regression

I have a data of 2000 (say locations of different fruits grow) and 10000 (say factors responsile for growth of fruits). And I also know that there are 20 different types of fruits in these locations.
I want to built a logistic model for this dataset such that if I get a new location then my model should be able to define the type of fruit.

```
log_reg_model = LogisticRegression(max_iter=500,penalty='l2',solver='newton-cg')
log_reg_model.fit(neighborhoodClass,target)
```

The shape of neighborhoodClass is (2000, 10000) and the target is an integer array of 20 integer labels of length 2000.

I believe that some of these fruit types are dependent on each other that means If I see a fruit A at location l1 then there is a high chance that I also observe fruit B in nearby location to l1.
That means fruit A and fruit B co-habitat in near proximity regions. Is there anyway I can add cross terms in logistic regression models to capture the neighborhood features?  So that when I see a new location with different features my model should be able to tell the type of the fruit?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Those are typically called interaction terms.

It appears you are using scikit-learn. Interaction terms can be automatically be generated in scikit-learn with [sklearn.preprocessing.PolynomialFeatures](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.PolynomialFeatures.html).

Comment: That was my thought when I read the title, but `I believe that some of these fruit types are dependent on each other that means If I see a fruit A at location l1 then there is a high chance that I also observe fruit B in nearby location to l1` makes me think this is a multi-label problem where predicting one fruit means that we should also predict another fruit to appear with a high probability.